# Can you divide this figure into two equal parts?

Tags: geometry, dissection

This is very simple when I see the answer, but I was not able to answer it(by thinking of single line), So posting for you.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply just do this to get it -

> [image]
>
>
>  Using a single *bent* line.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a straight line this would be how you'd do it:

> [image: Dividing the shape in 2 using single line]
>
>  So the line goes through 4 squares dividing them into 2 equal halves. Apart from these 4 squares, above the line, there are 4 squares, and below also 4 squares.

Comment: "Equal halves" in these puzzles tends to mean not merely equal area but equal shape.